# How To Format A Block of Code Within a Presentation?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, openoffice.org, google-docs, presentation

I am preparing a presentation using Google Slides, though I can also work on the presentation within Open Office that will include code snippets.

Is there any easy way to perform basic syntax highlighting on the code snippets with either Google Docs or Open Office Presenter?

**Edit:** Since I believe that I can find a way to embed HTML, any tools that can perform syntax highlighting on HTML would also be welcome suggestions.

Comment: If you copy from InteliJ products it will just work :)

Comment: Check out [Code Highlight](https://codehighlight.software) add-on. It highlights a block of code in Slides presentation. Supports a wide variety of syntaxes (React, Vue, C++, Go etc.) & offers the most popular themes on the market (VS Code, Cobalt, One Dark etc.)

Comment: use Visual Studio Code for the Web "https://vscode.dev/" and just copy paste or just copy paste from local VS Code

Answer (score 184, accepted):

An on-line syntax highlighter:

http://hilite.me/

Just copy and paste into your document.

Comment: Presentation no longer lets you add arbitrary html.

Comment: @iliacholy You can just copy and paste the text from the preview box instead of using the HTML code

Comment: it would be cool if it also indented..

Comment: https://romannurik.github.io/SlidesCodeHighlighter/

Comment: This service is unavailable

Comment: Hey @RobotEyes! looks like the service is not available now

Comment: I've added an alternative service

Comment: http://markup.su/highlighter/ is dead now, as well

Answer (score 23):

http://www.tohtml.com/ created syntax highlighted HTML code for lots of languages. It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: The problem is what to do after that. I installed qt-source-highlight and got the HTML. But OOO Presentation doesn't seems to have an option to insert HTML, nor can I find some program to export the syntax with another option (like RTF for example). For windows, I found this answer: http://www.fauskes.net/nb/syntaxms/ But I'm using LINUX and oowriter doesn't have this option.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Visual Studio (this might work in Eclipse also, but I never tried) and you copy & paste into Microsoft Word (or any other microsoft product) it will paste the code in whatever color your IDE had. Then you just need to copy the text out of word and into your desired application and it will paste as rich text.

I've only seen this work across Visual Studio to other Microsoft products though so I don't know if it will be any help.

Answer (score 8):

With the new [Add-Ons for Google Drive](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.no/2014/03/bring-little-something-extra-to-docs.html), you can get code highlighting with the [Code Pretty add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/code-pretty/igjbncgfgnfpbnifnnlcmjfbnidkndnh?utm_source=permalink).

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works for Doc and Spreadsheet and not Presentation, which is what the question is about.

Comment: now it works also for presentation. They probably added the feature

Comment: Can't tweak colors of this add on...made it less useful

Comment: @GameDeveloper how did yo umanage to get it working in presentations?

Comment: Oh. it was a old comment. Who remember.. so much changed in 2 years. Maybe I copy pasted from another editor supporting  markup. I really don't remember XD

Answer (score 4):

I've also thought of this. Finally, my solution is to use [github gist](https://gist.github.com). Don't forget it also has highlight functionality. Just copy it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just a few suggestions:

- Screenshots might be an easy way, but you'll have to make sure the code in the image is big enough and clear enough to read. (not the whole screenshot, just the relevant part)
- If you can embed html then there are lots of tools to generate syntax highlighted html.

Answer (score 2):

If you write your code in emacs then you might be interested in the [htmlize](http://web.archive.org/web/20080120061124/http://fly.srk.fer.hr/~hniksic/emacs/htmlize.el) elisp package.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://codepad.org.  It probably won't solve the poster's problem; but, I think it will be of use to others who read this article.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This isn't an article, it is the link to a tool that may have some of the desired features.  If the link changes and the tool becomes unavailable, the answer becomes irrelevant.